# iphone slow to recognize change of wifi access point

Tags: ios, network-programming, wifi

I have an app that needs to connect to a particular AP. This AP is not connected to the internet.  when i change networks in "settings"  to this new AP, i can see that i have received an ip address within a few seconds, but it takes 60-70 seconds for the wifi symbol in the status bar to appear. when i return to my app, i cannot connect to the AP until this symbol appears. once it appears, the connection works perfectly, but 60 seconds is a long time for the user to wait. I am using NSStreamManager to commuicate with the AP.

I do not understand why i can not connect as soon as settings shows an ip address. I know that apple does not allow for in-app control of network settings. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Further Information:

In an effort to understand the problem, I added a timer loop that starts as soon as i open the app, after changing to the new wifi network. it reports reachability status (via the apple reachability class) and attempts to get the SSID. if these two methods succeed then it sends a JSON message to the AP using streamManager, if not it calls itself again in one second.  The plug is reachable and the SSID readable, on the very first loop (less than 1 second) BUT it still takes stream manager the balance of the 60 seconds to complete. I don't believe the problem is on the AP side, as the android version of the app has no problem connecting.

```
-(BOOL)didConnect{
   NSString *ssidString=[self.serverCommManager fetchSSIDInfo];
   NSString *ssidStart=[ssidString substringToIndex:5];
   NSLog(@"****:didConnect ssidStart=%@ ",ssidStart);
   if([ssidStart isEqualToString:@"Ppppp"]){
       NSLog(@"****:didConnect isEqual=TRUE");
       self.streamManager = [[NSStreamManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
       [self.streamManager connectToHost:PlugHostName onPort:PlugPort withMessage:  [JSONQuery queryIsPlug]];
       [self removeWaitView];
        return YES;
    }else{

        NSLog(@"****:PlugSetupTVC didConnect isEqual=FALSE");
        [self startTimingWithInterval:1];
        return NO; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This discussion here seems relevant, but they don't seem to arrive at an answer: http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2009/Nov/msg00028.html

Comment: did you find the solution or the root cause to this?

Comment: What I THINK was happening was this: I was connecting to the AP with an ip address, not a domain name. The AP did not have a DNS. It seems that apple devices attempt to lookup a domain name, and until that lookup succeeds or times out, it doesn't connect. In fact I was able to reproduce the problem telnetting into the AP from my Macbook, but could connect instantly from a windows machine. We added a DNS to the AP, and then connected using a domain name. Instant connection!
 see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961791/nsstream-reverse-dns-lookup-error

Answer (score 0):

Because iOS( iOS7.0 below) will automatically try to ping(kinda) a random apple address to see if your device is connected to the INTERNET,so that's why the phenomena as what you described happens.

The iOS 7.0 above has a new feature that allows you to stop the automatically procedure to ping the addresses.

There is a solution,because iOS tries to get a result html file then it will show the wifi symbol,so i managed to modify the DNS configure and made a html file that contains the result just same as what it wish to get....
But i don't think it will help with your problem,because you are writing an app,so you cannot control the DNS,can you.