# NSStream - reverse DNS lookup error

Tags: ios, networking, network-programming, nsstream

I have to open an NSStream to a wifi access point that has only a numerical address, not a name. It takes NSStream 30-40 seconds to open a socket. In experimenting, i found that telnet-ing to the AP from a windows box was instantaneous, but on a mac, connecting the same 30-40 seconds. in researching telnet, i found that the implementation is a little different on a mac, in that it by default tries to to a name lookup. reading the manual page for telnet, i found:
-N      Prevents IP address to name lookup when destination host is given as an IP address.

when I used "telnet -N IP-address port", my connection was instantaneous! I suspect that this same problem is causing the delay in my NSStream connection. Is there any way to do the equivalent of setting the"-N" flag in NSStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like NSHost is not available on Cocoa Touch, so you cannot force a host with a given address, though I don't know if that negates the need for a dns lookup.

This problem has been around since 2005, though this might not apply to Cocoa Touch libraries. In any case there is no given solution:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Concepts/Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH4-SW10
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFSocketCreate

Comment: It looks to me as if using the CFSocket API would get around the problem.

Comment: I messed around with this and CFSocket (in this case via SimpleSocket) does indeed work